# "The input array was empty" ArgumentException when making a invoked cross thread call

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke

I have two separate threads and sometimes I need to call members from the other thread. I do this via the normal method of invoking. Here's the basic setup:

```
void Foo() //On thread 1
{
     if (this.InvokeRequired)
          this.Invoke(new Action(Foo2));
     else
          Foo2();
}

void Foo2(){/*Do Work*/} //Accesses members on thread 2
```

I'm getting the error "ArgumentException was unhandled: The input array was empty". The thing is, the method I'm trying to invoke has no parameters, and as per documentation, this shouldn't be an issue.

I even tried replacing:

```
this.Invoke(new Action(Foo2));
```

with

```
this.Invoke(new Action(Foo2), null);
```

(the documentation says if there are no parameters, then pass null, and I'm still getting the same error)

Here's the top of the StackTrace:

at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)

So, it says the array (for parameters I presume) is empty, but this is in fact correct because I'm calling a method with no parameters... What's the catch here?

Comment: Post contents of Foo2. I have a feeling this is an exception happening in the other thread, in Foo2, that MarshaledInvoke is just rethrowing. Also, go to Debug->Exceptions and check the box "Common language runtime exceptions", then try again. You will probably see this same exception raised, but somewhere inside Foo2.

Comment: Yeah, the error turned out to be when I was calling SendInput from user32. Thanks!